# php show upliner details by session

Tags: php

I have a code that displays the downliner details of a user, I want a code to display the upliner details of that user.
Confused?

> ### What's upliner and downliner?
>
> **Ok,** for example i am jazz,i referred John to this site, John registered with my link eg stackoverflow.com/signup?ref=jazz . So now john is  my **Downliner** and i am hes **upliner**.

```
  <?php
$sqlquery="SELECT username,country,doj,pcktaken FROM affiliateuser where referedby='".$_SESSION['username']."' ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1"; //fetching website from databse
$rec2=mysqli_query($con,$sqlquery);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($rec2);
$referusername=$row2[0];
$refcountry=$row2[1];
$refdate=$row2[2];
$refpckid=$row2[3];
$sqlquery11="SELECT name FROM packages where id = $refpckid"; //fetching no of days validity from package table from databse
$rec211=mysqli_query($con,$sqlquery11);
@$row211 = mysqli_fetch_row($rec211);
$refpckname=$row211[0]; //assigning we

                          ?>
```

The above code will display the details of the downliner. i want a code that will display the upliners details for the session of the logged in user. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i have sorted it out was just to create a new row in affiliateuser "upline" and select from there .

```
<?php
$sqlquery="SELECT username,country,doj,pcktaken FROM affiliateuser where upline='".$_SESSION['username']."' ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1"; //fetching website from databse
$rec2=mysqli_query($con,$sqlquery);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($rec2);
$referusername=$row2[0];
$refcountry=$row2[1];
$refdate=$row2[2];
$refpckid=$row2[3];
$sqlquery11="SELECT name FROM packages where id = $refpckid"; //fetching no of days validity from package table from databse
$rec211=mysqli_query($con,$sqlquery11);
@$row211 = mysqli_fetch_row($rec211);
$refpckname=$row211[0]; //assigning we

                          ?>
```